# What does "as used to" mean?

Tags: meaning

> It is rendered as DCDM at a 4K resolution as used to create the Master
>   video.

What does "as used to" mean? Does it mean "4K resolution which is used to create the Master video"?

I couldn't find the source link. It's about video formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, and the original sentence is **awkward**.    Please *don't* use the sample as an example of good technical writing.

The writer is trying to use the following meanings of "**as**":

> - **simultaneous changes**-- 
>     As you get older, moving house gets harder. *The two things happen at the same time.*
> - **We also use *as* to mean ‘in the way that’:** --  She arrived early, as I expected.
>
> --*[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as)*

The sentence means:

> - 4K resolution was used to create the Master video.
> - The copy ("it") is rendered in DCDM at 4K also.

Comment: Yes, except it's syntactically ambiguous as to whether the Master video was created using *a 4K resolution* OR using *DCDM at a 4K resolution*.